# Secret appregistry-mw-proxy-secret not found after deploying HCL Connections Customizer Helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-connections, hcl-component-pack

I'm installing the component pack 6.5.0.0 for HCL Connections. Orient me works, but [after deploying the customizer](https://help.hcltechsw.com/connections/v65/admin/install/cp_install_customizer.html), my `mw-proxy` pods got stuck at ContainerCreating. They show the following event log error:

```
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "appregistry-mw-proxy-secret-vol" : secrets "appregistry-mw-proxy-secret" not found
```

I never heared of those secret and looked inside the chart. `mw-proxy-cloud-deployment.yaml` try to mount those secret:

```
  volumes:
    - name: nfs
      persistentVolumeClaim:
       claimName: customizernfsclaim
    - name: appregistry-mw-proxy-secret-vol
      secret:
        secretName: appregistry-mw-proxy-secret
```

The problem is that I could not found any information what this secret is for and how it should be mounted. In the documentation they just require bootstrap, connections-env and infrastructure charts. All of them were installed. I just tried creating some file as secret:

```
echo Test123 > pwd-test
k create secret generic appregistry-mw-proxy-secret --from-file=pwd-test
```

After deleting all the pods, they came up running. But I don't know what this secret is for and what the customizer expects. Maybe this break some functionality of the application.

My questions are:

- What is this secret for?
- How do I create it correctly? (User, password, certificate, whatever)
- Is there any documentation about it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the parameter 
env.force_regenerate=true
to the bootstrap helmchart ?
There's also the createSecret=true in the connections-env helm chart.

Comment: `env.force_regenerate: true` was already set, but no `createSecret`. After setting `createSecret: true` and re-deploying (`helm delete --purge` with new deployment), the bootstrap bot throw an error: `403 response when trying to configure redis on an auth enabled server.`

Answer (score 0):

If you used this [documentation](https://help.hcltechsw.com/connections/v65/admin/install/cp_install_services_tasks.html),
the order of the helm deployments is wrong.
The infrastructure deployment creates the secret "appregistry-mw-proxy-secret". So, first deploy infrastructure and after that mw-proxy and the pods will start.